# scanning pages in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, scanning

I'd like to scan multiple pages via c++. The idea is that the user puts the pages into the scanner and then presses a button of my application and the pages are scanned at 300 dpi and stored as PNG files.

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if you mentioned an operating system and specific device.  I doubt there is any portable C++ code that will do this with any scanner on any operating system.

Comment: Right, surely C++ is not the appropriate language for this task.  Probably PowerShell could be a better starting point (assuming one has already installed some scanner software to do the heavy lifting).

Comment: It should work on Windows 7 32 and 64-bit systems. I don't know the scanner brand or model, but if I have to write device-specific code for each brand/model I'm not going to implement this feature.

Comment: @JohnZwinck how would it work with powershell? Assuming this would work, couldn't I just lauch the powershell commands from c++?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the [Windows Image Acquisition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Image_Acquisition) API

Comment: Free applications like Irfanview support similar features, so this should be possible. The keywords you probably need to do research on are WIA and TWAIN.

Comment: Have you tried a search for "image scanner api"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for "PowerShell scanner" and found this right away:

http://cerealnumber.livejournal.com/47638.html

It's not that much code, and I think you only need the first 20 lines or so.  The best part is you don't need any sort of development tools to try it.